# GLFW Window on MacBook 16" displaying content only in upper left of window

Tags: c++, window, glfw, vulkan

I have a weird problem with GLFW on my MacBook Screen. I am creating a 1400 by 900 pixel window on my nearly 4k screen (3456 x 2234), so it should be really tiny. Instead what happens is that the window is 4 times the size (double in length and height) and my rendered content is only being displayed in the upper left of the screen.

[image: My Window]

I know that apple does some sketchy mapping stuff because of their wird aspect ratio display, but I searched for quite a while and no one has had the same problem.

What's even weirder is that if I create that window on an external monitor and drag it onto to laptop display, it works just fine. It only messes up when created on the laptop display itself.

I am using GLFW 3.3 and Vulkan 1.2.198 on macOS Monterey 12.1

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: After trying nearly everything possible in my code and getting the same bug when using the minimal example from [the GLFW getting started example](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/vulkan_guide.html), I came to the conclusion that this isn't code related as pointed out in the comments.

Comment: Without knowing the code in form of a [mcve] it is hard to say what you did wrong and how to fix it. But MacBooks with retina displays have two “coordinate” systems. One representing the actual display pixels and one the mapped ones. It think the window dimension in glfw are the mapped coordinates and the viewport has to be in pixels.

Comment: A minimal reproducible example with all the code needed to create a vulkan viewport would be way too much so I don't think that's a good idea in this case. But thank you for that tip, I will try to adjust my viewport size.

Comment: Yes that’s true. But it should still be more then just text, and have some relevant code that would allow to reproduce the problem.

Comment: How did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an issue with how Mac displays report their resolution. Note that this is not a silver bullet but, when faced with the same issue, this worked for me.

The short of it is that the values that you're using to calculate your viewport are incorrect due to how the Mac display scales. The solution that I've found is to *ask* GLFW what you should set.

To get these values, just use the following function call. I am not sure what the `glViewport` equivalent is in vulkan, but this should theoretically work, and worked for me in OpenGL for the same problem.

```cpp
int initial_framebuffer_width, initial_framebuffer_height;
glfwGetFramebufferSize(g_glfw_window, &initial_framebuffer_width,
                         &initial_framebuffer_height);
// Set your viewport here with the width and height.
```

If this didn't work, a good debugging step is to draw the window, then attempt to resize just a tiny bit, then print out the width and height values that GLFW gives in the framebuffer callback. You should notice that they might be much larger than what you set them to, this is how you know it's the scaling issue, and the above code should give you what you're looking for.